# Affine cipher gets the same key in C language

Tags: c, encryption

I tried to encrypt an affine cipher reading from text file. My `.txt` files include two key: `alpha` and `beta`. `Alpha` should be an odd number because `gcd(alpha, 26)==1` 
and generate random key. Here is my code:

```
beta = rand() % 26;
```

but encryption doesn't work correctly. For example: the encrypted word `"bahar"`, when encrypted, turns out in the `"XWDWN"` word but it should be start `"M"` not `"X"`. Keys are `alpha = 3` and `beta = 9` but my code selected `key (1, 22) alpha=1 beta=22`. Constantly alpha has been selected `"1"`. Another encryption for example `(1, 17)`.. etc.

Comment: I think `putc` works correctly but not how you imagine. `putc` is developed and used from long time, so have no doubt about it ;) Also prefer `'A'` instead of 65 to create letter from number

Comment: I do not know why alpha is always 1 but you are doing your encryption wrong. This is how encryption looks E(x)=alpha*x + beta. And your encryption looks as follows: E(x) =  (x + beta) + (65*alpha)

Comment: Just a note, in case alpha is 13 you won't be able to decrypt.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to encrypt

```
putc(((toupper(p) - 'A')*alpha + beta) % 26 + 'A', cipher);
```

Comment: More like this `putc(((toupper(c) - beta - 65) * r) % 26 + 65, decrypt);`